# Dead or Alive turtle jumping Algorithm

Tags: algorithm

River is divided into n segments breadth wise, with either stone or water [ 1,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1... ].A turtle is present on one side of the bank and he can make a move with speed of x, x speed means he can cross x segments of the river at a single time.
After making a cross with x speed, he can acquire, either of these three speeds, x,x+1,x-1.
He can move in both directions.

Now 1 represents stone and 0 represents water.
If the turtle jumps into water he dies, but if he makes a jump on stone, then he can acquire new speed according to the given rule.

Given no. of segments (n), distribution of segment(array[n]), and the initial speed(x).
Find is there any possibility of the turtle making it to the other side of the bank ?

I've solved this problem recursively, but not able to do using non-recursive method.

Turtle on one side||1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,....||Other side of the river

Comment: what is your recursive solution?

Comment: Its sort of a brute force approach,
 1)I'm constantly checking for cases when turtle will be dead, that can be case when all three speeds will hit water.

2) It can always make a valid exit, if at any point of time distance between bank and current position is less than x. Based on this cases and few more I made a recursive approach, allowing every current position to recurse in possible positions ahead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically it's a simple search problem, where your states are tuples of the current position of the turtle and it's speed. It can be implemented without recursion using a stack (depth first) or a queue (breadth first search). Here's an implementation using a queue, i.e., breadth-first, in Python:

```py
from collections import deque

def cross_river(river, position=0, speed=1):
    queue = deque([(position, speed, [])])
    visited = set()
    while queue:
        position, speed, path = queue.popleft()

        # if  last stone of river, return sequence of jumps to get there
        if position == len(river) - 1:
            return path

        # check whether we've been here before
        if (position, abs(speed)) in visited:
            continue
        visited.add((position, abs(speed)))

        # for all possible jumps, add the new state to the queue
        for i in [-1, 0, +1]:    # change in speed
            for k in [-1, +1]:   # change in direction
                new_spd = (speed + i) * k
                new_pos = position + new_spd
                if 0 <= new_pos < len(river) and river[new_pos] == 1:
                    queue.append((new_pos, new_spd, path + [new_spd]))

print cross_river([1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1])  # Result: [2, -2, 3, 4, 3]
```

(In fact, this algorithm is a bit stricter than what's described in your question, as the turtle has to to land *exactly* on the last stone, instead of anywhere on the other side, but this should be easy to change.)